# jQuery selector problem: clicking one element will modify the immediate next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I want to use jquery to slidedown the description classes when title classes are clicked. However, what I want to do is when a specific title is clicked, only the immediate next description should slidedown. How can I do that in  one block of code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".title").click(function(){
  $(".description").slideToggle();
 })
})
```

```html
<div> <h2 class="title">title</h2> 
   <table class="description">description</table> 
</div>

<div> <h2 class="title">title</h2> 
   <table class="description">description</table> 
</div>

<div> <h2 class="title">title</h2> 
   <table class="description">description</table> 
</div>

<div> <h2 class="title">title</h2> 
   <table class="description">description</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".description").slideToggle();` takes all elements with `class=description`, not just the one you want.

Use `next()` near the selected one title.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".title").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".description").slideToggle();
    })
})
```